# MacOS - Script works when run in shell but not when opened with terminal

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I am trying to write a script for a Mac which will run each `.jar` file in its directory sequentially.  I used a for loop to iterate over the files like so:

```
for i in *.jar; do
  java -jar "$i" "$@"
done
```

This works perfectly on my Linux machine and when I invoke it from the shell using `./runJars.sh`, but when I run the script by using Open with>Terminal, it fails.

When opening it with Terminal, the loop runs once and java outputs an error stating that it cannot load the file `*.jar`, so I have concluded the file expansion is not occurring for some reason when it is opened with the Terminal.  Everything before that runs correctly.

I have tried adding a line `files=*.jar` then looping over `$files`, but that doesn't work either.  I have tried looping over `$(ls *.jar)`, but that fails if the file name has embedded spaces.

What I would like to know is why this fails in the Terminal and how I could fix it.

Comment: Have you tried printing "$i" to see its value? are you sure you are standing by default in the Terminal on the same directory where you want to execute this? You could add a "cd somewhere" so you are 100% sure you are no matter how you invoke the script

Comment: Yes, try echoing the current directory to make sure you are where you think you are. Also, do you have a "shebang" line?

Comment: Show the full script. Like @Mort asked, is there a shebang or any other lines in the script. Also, what is the login shell and version of your terminal as compared to the shebang you have declared in the script? – Furthermore, what is the output of `pwd` in your script? You may just simply need to `cd` like @MatiasBarrios mentioned.

Comment: I thought that if there were no jar files, `*.jar` would evaluate to an empty string, but further testing shows it just evaluates to `*.jar`.  Changing directories to the current directory of the script should work, then.  I will test it when I have access to the computer again.  Thanks for the help, guys

Comment: *"I thought that ... evaluate to an empty string"* would only apply if `nullglob` is enabled.

Comment: put `shopt -s nullglob` in your script to use this feature.

Comment: Scripts opened from the Finder run with their working directory set to your home folder, not the directory the script is in. Hence `*.jar` is looking for .jar files in your home folder. If this is not what you wanted, you'll need to do something in the script to tell it where to look.